# Issue related to WCF Service Hosted On IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I have hosted a WCF Service On IIS Server, I have given the SSL Certificate and and have installed the server certificates from the makecert.exe command line.But when i hit the Service.svc.

I got a following error :

> Keyset does not exist and related to cryptography...

My Web.Config File is like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
        Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
        web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
        the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
        A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
        machine.config.comments usually located in 
        \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
    -->
    <configuration>
        <!--<configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                        <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                        <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                        <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                        <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    </sectionGroup>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>-->
        <appSettings/>
        <connectionStrings/>
        <system.web>
            <!--
                Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
                symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
                affects performance, set this value to true only 
                during development.
            -->
            <compilation debug="true">
                <assemblies>
                    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                </assemblies>
            </compilation>
            <!--
                The <authentication> section enables configuration 
                of the security authentication mode used by 
                ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
            -->
            <authentication mode="Windows"/>
            <!--
                The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
                of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
                during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
                it enables developers to configure html error pages 
                to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
                <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
                <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
            </customErrors>
            -->
            <pages>
                <controls>
                    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                </controls>
            </pages>
            <httpHandlers>
                <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
                <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
            </httpHandlers>
            <httpModules>
                <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </httpModules>
        </system.web>
        <system.codedom>
            <compilers>
                <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
                </compiler>
            </compilers>
        </system.codedom>
        <!--<system.web.extensions>
            <scripting>
                <webServices>
                    <authenticationService enabled="true"
                       requireSSL ="true"/>
                </webServices>
            </scripting>
        </system.web.extensions>-->

        <!--
            The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
            Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
        -->
        <system.webServer>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
            <modules>
                <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </modules>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
                <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
        <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
                <wsHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
                        <security>
                            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                        </security>
                    </binding>
                </wsHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <services>
                <service name="WsHttpCertificates.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WsHttpCertificates.Service1Behavior">
                    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                    <endpoint address="http://localhost:1974/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="WsHttpCertificates.IService1">
                        <!-- 
                  Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
                  identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
                  automatically.

              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost"/>
              </identity>-->
                    </endpoint>
                    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
                    <!--<host>
                        <baseAddresses>
                            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1974/Service1.svc"/>
                        </baseAddresses>
                    </host>-->
                </service>
            </services>
            <behaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="WsHttpCertificates.Service1Behavior">
                        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:1974/Service1.svc"/>
                        <serviceCredentials>
                            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true"/>
                            <clientCertificate>
                                <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
                            </clientCertificate>
                            <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" findValue="a2 62 7e c8 4a 46 08 99 43 80 fc 5e b2 23 1d 3b" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
                        </serviceCredentials>
                        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                    </behavior>
                </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Could any body help me in getting rid of this error..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to host on https, you probably need mexHttpsBinding in the config.  Modify your first attempt and see if that solves it?

Comment: change address="http://localhost:1974/Service1.svc"                        as                                                                  address=""

Comment: I have changed the address too.But it is giving the same error.